# How come when I cast down I cannot access the subclass properties?

Tags: java, netbeans, casting

```
class Casting
{
    main()
    {
        //instantiate the subclass MotoX
        CellPhone myPhone = new MotoX("motorola", "white", true, 5);
        MotoX phone = (MotoX) myPhone;
        //I tried to call MotoX methods using myPhone 
        //however netbeans only showed the properties within the CellPhone class
    }
}
```

I know a down cast serves to convert, if you will, a super class to a more specific subtype, however when I do so I don't gain access to the MotoX class' properties.

Answer (score 1):

`myPhone` is defined as a `CellPhone`. If you want to use `Motox` methods, you should either define it as a `Motox`:

```
Motox myPhone = new MotoX("motorola", "white", true, 5);
```

Or explicitly cast it when you use it:

```
CellPhone myPhone = new MotoX("motorola", "white", true, 5);
((Motox) myPhone).someMotoxMethod();
```

Comment: OP did an explicit downcast.

Comment: @Turing85 - on `phone`. This won't help him to call methods on `myPhone`.

Comment: thanks! so what would be the point of upcasting like i did? (CellPhone myPhone = new MotoX(); )

Comment: @Bryan you gain the abstraction. You could later replace `myPhone`'s instansiation with any other `CellPhone` implementation and have the rest of your code unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You used the wrong variable. You tried to access the MotoXmethods from `myPhone`. However `phone` is the variable of type `MotoX`. Simply use `phone` instead of `myPhone` and you can access properties of `MotoX`.

Comment: i'm starting to understand, so if i were to do, for example, (MotoX phone = (MotoX) myPhone; ) the "phone" variable would be assigned to the myPhone variable? what would be the point of doing so?

Comment: @Bryan i think you have a general misconception about inheritance. If you have a variable of type `CellPhone` (regardless of what is assigned to it), you can only access methods which are defined in the class `CellPhone`. Downcasting, on the other hand, allows you to access methods known by the subclass, but not by the superclass.